# Selectively print a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, writer

I have a PHP multidimensional array that I need to *selectively* print to excel writer. I have something like this:

```
array(2) {
  [10227]=>
  array(9) {
    ["user"]=>
    string(5) "10227"
    ["talk_time"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["acw"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["idle"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [10236]=>
  array(9) {
    ["user"]=>
    string(5) "10236"
    ["talk_time"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["acw"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["idle"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

And in excel I need it to look kinda' like this:

```
User  | talk_time  | acw  | idle
10227 | 8          | 0    | 6
10236 | 10         | 3    | 0
```

I think I can manage the 'writing' to excel, but I cannot seem to get the php to selectively write the value for each field where and how I want it. I've read a lot and have tried many things, I think the answer would be to use two foreach loops one for the 'initial' array and another one for the second dimension array, but for some reason I cannot make it work. I've also tried using 'extract' but it didn't go too well... I'm not a 'trained' PHP programmer. Google has been my university (and stackoverflow my faculty) and though I don't have too much trouble working with arrays..., the world goes upside down with multidimensional arrays...

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

-----EDIT-----
Ok, I do not need the 'export to Excel' feature, I can handle that once I can assign the value of the array to a variable.

I'm currently doing this:

```
foreach ($agents as $row){
  $USER=$row["user"];
  echo "$USER\n";
  foreach($row as $col){
  $TALK_SEC=$col["talk_sec"];
  }
}
```

But all I'm getting is

```
1023610236102361023610236102361023610236102361023610236102361023610236102361023610236102361023610236102361023610236
```

which is my first agent (I'm limiting my query to 1 -LIMIT 1-) times 24 times. If I add an echo to `$TALK_SEC`, I would get the first number of each of the three four fields I'm querying about times the 24 times the agent will be 'spit' out....

FINAL EDIT AND ANSWER

I was able to get it to work using actually a single foreach statement:

```
foreach ($agents as $row){
    //VAR_DUMP($row);
    $USER=$row['user'];
    $TALK=$row['talk_time'];
    $ACW=$row['acw'];
    $IDLE=$row['idle'];
```

Now all I have to do is print the variable names (`$USER`, `$TALK`, etc...) in the spreadsheet that I've already created with `PEAR::EXCEL_WRITER`. Of course you need to create a loop to iterate over the different `$USERS` that your query will output.

Comment: One moment i know that you want..

you need genarate table html with this array and put some params on the header..

Comment: Please post the PHP code that you've tried.

Comment: Sorry..

I forgot "<?php" at begin

Comment: I test now and it works. Don't work for you?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the SUPER quick response...! The answer is almost there but not quite. Here's the deal, I use this Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php (Pear's Spreadsheet writer) to write the fields on excel. What I need to do is print the specific value per element in the $array[]. I use something like $sheet2->write(2,3,$VALUE-TO-PRINT,$format); how to print each value (talk_time, for instance) in the $VALUE-TO-PRINT field just up there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script can generate file excel. But in your case you need format your array to put:

```
User  | talk_time  | acw  | idle
10227 | 8          | 0    | 6
10236 | 10         | 3    | 0
```

The Script:

```
<?php

$file="demo.xls";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
$array = array(
    array(10, 15, 20),
    array(10, 15, 20),
    array(10, 15, 20)
);
?>
<table>
<?php foreach($array as $row): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach($row as $col):?>
        <td><?php echo $col ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an addition to the answer already posted here... It just shows how to include the headings for the array in the Excel file.  Mark the other person's post as answered, not mine, if this is what does it for you.

output:

```
user    talk_time   acw      idle
10227   8           0        6
10236   10          3        0
```

code:

```
<?php
$array = 
      array (
        10227 => 
        array (
          'user' => '10227',
          'talk_time' => '8',
          'acw' => '0',
          'idle' => '6',
        ),
        10236 => 
        array (
          'user' => '10236',
          'talk_time' => '10',
          'acw' => '3',
          'idle' => '0',
        ),
      );  
$file="demo.xls";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");

$index = array_slice($array,0,1);  
$index = array_keys($index[0]);   

?>
<table> 
    <tr>
      <?php foreach($index as $heading): ?>
        <th><?php echo $heading ?></th>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr> 
    <?php foreach($array as $row): ?>
    <tr>
       <?php foreach($row as $col):?>
          <td><?php echo $col ?></td>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```